# how to use noConflict for 2 js functions?

Tags: javascript

I have a different js framework and it stop below script.

So I read that I must using The noConflict() Method.

I try do it but just first function works. and second function do not works!

(if replace loction these two  functions,Always only first function works.

what is my mistake?

I used this tutorial on w3school to do it.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_noconflict.asp

Also I try `var jq = $.noConflict();` and other method.

I use this script inline in my html codes.

```
  function checkCitySelect()
  {
          $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("#province, #county, #district,#selectSubject").on('change', function() {
    var txt;
var type = this.id;
txt = $("#"+type).val();

$.post("ajax/validation.php", {value: txt,id: type}, function(result){
    if(type == 'province')
        $("#county").empty().append(result);
    else if(type == 'county')
        $("#district").empty().append(result);
    else if(type == 'district')
    {
          setAddressMap2("Paris, France");
    }
    else if(type == 'selectSubject')
    {
          $("#selectSubject").after(result);
    }

    });
});
});
      }


   function setAddressMap2(whereis)
  {
      $.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $("#signup_map").gmap3({
  getlatlng:{
    address:  whereis,
    callback: function(results){
      if ( !results ) return;
      $(this).gmap3({
        marker:{
          latLng:results[0].geometry.location
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
});
}


      checkCitySelect();
      setAddressMap2("JAPAN");

  </script>
```

Comment: It probably won't fix your code but `$.noConflict();` must be outside of any function. Official doc: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/. Good luck.

Comment: Put it in script tag immediately after jQuery.js loads and make sure jQuery.js loads before the other library